# Parsing a float and return it in a function

Tags: java, numberformatexception

```
public static float fahrenheitEnCelsius(int f) {
    float cel = 5 / 9.0F * (f - 32);
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
    Float formatedFloat = new Float(formatter.format(cel));
    return formatedFloat;
}
```

I have function that takes an integer input of a value in Fahrenheit and returns the value in celsius with only one decimal after the comma. I am getting this error for an input value 2006 :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,096.7"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
at java.lang.Float.<init>(Float.java:532)
at seance11mai.fahrenheitEnCelsius(seance11mai.java:42)
at seance11mai.main(seance11mai.java:47)
```

Comment: Why are you doing all that formatting and parsing? It doesn't make sense. You're converting the number to a string and then back to a number again. Note that the number of digits after the decimal point is not a property of numbers. What you're doing does not make the `float` have one digit after the decimal point.

Comment: @Jesper "It doesn't make sense" - true, but not relevant any more. At some point, people will type `fahrenheit celsius java` into google, find this question, copy the nonsense that is currently the accepted answer, and it will "work". Full score on their assignment. One step closer to their MSc. Sense? You seem to set the wrong priorities here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can better return the string instead of float by changing the method to `public static float fahrenheitEnCelsius(int f)`

If you really wants to return a float try this :

```
public static float fahrenheitEnCelsius(int f) {
    float cel = 5 / 9.0F * (f - 32);
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
    String temp = formatter.format(cel);
    temp = temp.replaceAll("[,;\\s]","");
    Float formatedFloat = new Float(temp);
    System.out.println(formatedFloat);
    return formatedFloat;
 }
```

Comment: `1,096.7` is a valid representation of a floating point number. Formatting is complex. (BTW: I thought that it could be hard to write an answer that makes even less sense than the question....)

Comment: This "solves" the problem, but is still based on the incorrect notion that a `float` somehow remembers how it is formatted.

Comment: @Jesper I'm pretty sure that the goal of all these formatting contortions was to limit the number of decimal places for the result (and in that regard, a float can ""remember"" how it was formatted, *with many caveats*). The approach was wrong. The solution is *wronger*. We're likely facing an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Answer (score 2):

You will have the `NumberFormatException` for any floating input, whose Celsius conversion results in 1,000 or more in result. Because `NumberFormat` for the given locale will add a thousand separator to the output, and the `String` becomes invalid input for the `Float` constructor

```
public Float(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
        value = parseFloat(s);
    }
```

The reason you don't get any exception for inputs upto 1831 f is because the resultant value of `cel` is lower than 1,000

Also, it appears that the intention to use `NumberFormat` class is to set the decimal scale. The same result can be achieved with `String.format` as shown below

```
 public static float fahrenheitEnCelsius(int f) {
        float cel = 5 / 9.0F * (f - 32);
        String value = String.format("%.1f", cel);
        return Float.valueOf(value);
    }
```

Even so the given method is doing more than one thing

1. Converting Fahrenheit to Celsius
2. Formatting value of result

It's better to return the value as computed and apply formatting only when displaying/printing the result.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this because the String provided to the Float constructor in not in the good format.

```
new Float("22222.3333") //deprecated
Float.valueOf("22222.3333")
```

The Float class is expecting a String in the "Float format" for exemple -20234.23 or 34.255

What you provided is a Localized String representation of a float using the Locale.US

```
formatter.format(cel)     // returned actually 1,096.7  not ( 1096.7)
```

To convert back the string "1,096.7" to a float you can use

```
formatter.parse(aString)  // throws ParseException
```

So

```
Float formatedFloat = new Float(formatter.format(cel));
```

Could be replaced by

```
Float formatedFloat = formatter.parse(formatter.format(cel));
```

On a final note, fahrenheitEnCelsius() might be just fine returning a float without any decimal digit rounding.

If you need to "print" or "display" fahrenheitEnCelsius() then you might use another function just taking care of the formatting using the NumberFormat or DecimalFormat.

Hope this helps.